# How to open salesforce login screen within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, salesforce

I am using salesforce oauth connected app setup. When I launch the app it redirects me to login in the safari in app browser. How to control this? Do I need to use any salesforce library like zksforce.

I followed these steps to create a project: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/ios_new_force_project.htm

Please suggest me which is the right way to display login screen in a native app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open login screen native -as far as I know :)-

You should set properties first as :

```
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].connectedAppId = RemoteAccessConsumerKey;
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].connectedAppCallbackUri = OAuthRedirectURI;
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].authScopes = @[ @"web", @"api" ];
```

you can set callback properties if necessary :

```
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].postLaunchAction = ^(SFSDKLaunchAction launchActionList) {

    };
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].launchErrorAction = ^(NSError *error, SFSDKLaunchAction launchActionList) {

    };
```

And Then you should call :

```
    [[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager] launch];
```